# How i group the result according to 2.degree association in activerecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I am trying to group blog_post that is related to category. category is related to category_group. So there is no organic bond between blog_post and category_group.

How can I group the results?

```
blog_post  -> category -> category_group 

blog_post     category     group
text          name         name
title         slug_name    slug_name
category_id   group_id
```

i want the blog_post to group according to category_group.
 so is it possible or no make sense?

Comment: Did you try anything? Can we have more code?

Comment: post the association between those models.

Comment: i am sorry for this. but i edited the question. i hope it is understandable.